# JDBC- Implementation of interfaces

Tags: java, jdbc

In JDBC, to connect and execute statements in DB we mainly make use of Connection,Statement and ResultSet which  are interfaces. But their corresponding objects is later used to run methods like createStatement(),executeQuery(),next() etc.Which class implements these methods?
Why it is called as connection object instead of implemented class object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JDBC you first register a driver by calling

```
Class.forName('classname')
```

which loads the Database class and registers that class with `DriverManager`

When you say `DriverManager.getConnection(`) - It returns you `java.sql.Connection` (the contract as per specification)

> Which class implements these methods?

The actual implementation is provided by the database vendor, for e.g. Oracle, MySQL.

> Why it is called as connection object instead of implemented class
>   object?

Because you [code to Interface and not implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) (good coding practice).

If you want you can look up in the vendor jar and find which class implements Connection then instead of

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection()
```

you can write

```
VendorConnectionImpl vendorConnection = (VendorConnectionImpl)DriverManager.getConnection()
```

This above will work but then it will bind you with that specific implementation.

If you want to move from vendor1 to vendor2 you cannot do that, first you will have to change the above code as per vendor2 API, But if you use the first approach you can move from Vendor to Vendor without having pain of changing your code.

Comment: I am just trying to understand the concept. is it the class that we load in Class.forName() implement these methods?

Comment: Say for MySQL the class implementing java.sql.Connection interface is com.mysql.Connnection, similarly for Driver, PreparedStatement and others

Comment: k.If there is class A and class B implementing interface C.If i said Cobject.methodinC(), how compiler knows which implementation has to be considered?

Comment: To call Cobject.methodinC(), you would do something like C Cobject = new CImpl(); At runtime, CImpl will be used, please create a new question next time

Comment: Since JDBC 4 (Java 6) it is no longer necessary to 'load' the driver using `Class.forName` (if you are using a JDBC 4 compliant driver)

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually do

```
Connection conn = new Connection();
```

You do something like

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
     DB_PATH + "?user=" + USER_NAME + "&password=" + USER_PASS); 
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

But to answer your question directly No you cannot instantiate an `Interface` you have to use a class that `implements` the `Interface` or use a Proxy.

Comment: k.But my question is which class implement createStatement(),executQuery() methods of interface?

Comment: every class that implements the `Statement` interface have to override the `executeQuery()` method (as well as any other methods of the interface). Which one you are using depends on how the `conn.createStatement()` works and what it actually returns.

Comment: k.I know that .We used to create an object of class that implements interface and calls corresponding method of that interface.. but here it is directly calling the method with the object of interface. How the methods got override without a class?

Comment: If you want the actual class name you print out `conn.getClass()` and it will tell you the name but you really shouldn't be using the concrete class the `JDBC` is designed to work through its interfaces.

Comment: I am not trying to implement this interface in my class. I just want to know the concept of using interface object and accessing methods of that interface like Statement.executeQuery(query).

Comment: Ok. If you have an variable declared as an interface like `Connection conn;` Once you have created an instance of an Object implementing that interface (however you do that for the given interface) you can use all the methods defined by that interface because Java knows that the variable's Class implements the interface and therefore has all the methods of that interface available to it. You cannot use a method defined by the Class that isn't in the interface unless you cast the variable to that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an interface class. You'll have either implement that interface yourself or use [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) to create an instance of said interface that will delegate all calls to provided [InvocationHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html).

Answer (score 0):

These guys are answering your question but I don't think that you are getting it from the comments.

You need to actually implement the interface by creating your own class.  So create a class that implements the interface, include the correct abstract methods, and then add whatever you want to the functionality in your new class.  Then you'll instantiate that class to use the functions.

An interface is like a programming "contract"  it's there to make sure that any class used that extends the interface fulfills certain functions, however, you can't instantiate the interface itself to use its' methods, you inherit them/override them in your new class.   After you override the abstract methods in your new class you can program in whatever else you want your particular interface extension class to do.

http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-abstract-class-and-interface
and
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2001-04/03-qa-0420-abstract.html
will let you read up on these topics.

Comment: Downvote for linking basic concepts that this person doesn't seem to understand?  The OP is obviously struggling with inheritance and interfaces and previous answers didn't point to background material.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following explanation will help.

Q: Where does the driver **Connection implementation** come from? And the implementation of Statement and ResultSet?

```java
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
// String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?user=root&password=root";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Small tip: the driver implementation is loaded as soon as the DriverManager class is loaded(initialized).

Take the source code of mysql-connector-java:5.1.36 for example.

● class **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** extends class **NonRegisteringDriver**, in which there is a method named **connect()** which returns an instance of Connection.
pay attention to the **registeredDrivers** field of NonRegisteringDriver

```java
public class Driver extends NonRegisteringDriver implements java.sql.Driver {
...
public java.sql.Connection connect(String url, Properties info) throws SQLException {
```

● mysql driver is registered and the driver is added to **registeredDrivers**:

```java
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
...
java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver()); // from com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
...
registeredDrivers.addIfAbsent(new DriverInfo(driver, da));  // mysql driver instance is added to registeredDrivers
```

from now on **JDBC** knows that there is one JDBC implementation, namely mysql.

● Then create connection:

```java
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

● Follow the source code of **DriverManager.getConnection**
Pay attention to the **registeredDrivers**
Here **connection implementation** is created by **aDriver.driver.connect**

```java
for(DriverInfo aDriver : registeredDrivers) {
...
     Connection con = aDriver.driver.connect(url, info);
...
}
```

● Since connection implementation for mysql has been found, the implementation of **Statement** and **ResultSet** can also be found by digging into the source code of mysql-connector-java:5.1.36

```java
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
// String sql = "select * from user";
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

As for **JDBC 4**, driver implementation will be automatically detected from the classpath when the class DriverManager is loaded:
[DriverManager.java#l101](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/sql/DriverManager.java#l101)

```java
static {
    loadInitialDrivers();
    println("JDBC DriverManager initialized");
}

...

private static void loadInitialDrivers() {
...
    ServiceLoader<Driver> loadedDrivers = ServiceLoader.load(Driver.class);
...
}
```

content of file mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar!/**META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver**:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver
```